# Apps Script: Append row and automatically add additional details that newly created row

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have 2 server-side scripts handling information coming from an html form. The first script stores the user input in the last available row in my Google sheet. The second script adds some additional information to the next available cells of that newly created row in the same Google sheet.

Both scripts have been working pretty fine. But it is a little bit annoying that I have to always run the second script manually or with a time based trigger. So, here is my question: How can I make these 2 scripts run **automatically one after another** or combine them into one single script?

**Script 1** (appends new row)

```
function AddRecord(comapny, salutation, name, phone, email, appointment, room) {
  var url = 'SHEET_URL';
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var webAppSheet = ss.getSheetByName("SHEE_ID");

  webAppSheet.appendRow([comapny, salutation, name, phone, email, appointment, room]);
}
```

**Script 2** (adds additional details to the newly appended row)

```
function addMoreDetailsToRecord() {
  var url = 'SHEET_URL';
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var webAppSheet = ss.getSheetByName("SHEE_ID");

  var data = webAppSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var data_len = data.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < data_len; i++) {
    if (data[i][7] == "8:00 AM" && data[i][9] === "" && data[i][10] === "") {
      webAppSheet.getRange(i + 1, 9).setValue("NEW APPOINTMENT");
      webAppSheet.getRange(i + 1, 10).setValue("ROOM NUMBER ONE");
      webAppSheet.getRange(i + 1, 11).setValue("NAME OF ORGANIZER");
    }
    else if (data[i][7] == "10.00AM" && data[i][9] === "" && data[i][10] === "") {
      webAppSheet.getRange(i + 1, 9).setValue("NEW APPOINTMENT");
      webAppSheet.getRange(i + 1, 10).setValue("ROOM NUMBER TWO");
      webAppSheet.getRange(i + 1, 11).setValue("NAME OF ORGANIZER");
    }
  }
}
```

Thank you so much in advance for your help and hints.

Comment: Why don't you check for the field value in data[i][7] and set the other values in the first function ? Is it being calculated in the sheet ?

Comment: @Karan: Not possible, because it is the second function that needs input from the first fuction and not the other way around. No, the values in the second function never change/are always the same and will simply be added to the next empty cells of the newly appended row based on the values retuned by the first fonction.

Comment: Where's the value of data[i][7] coming from ?

Comment: @Karan - `data[i][7]` is in the second function `addMoreDetailsToRecord()`. It gets its value from the first function `AddRecord(comapny, salutation, name, phone, email, appointment, room)`. And that value is whatever the user input for `appointment` is. That user input is always a date (so, DD/MONTH/YEAR) in the html-file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call your second script from within your first one.

```
function AddRecord(comapny, salutation, name, phone, email, appointment, room) {
  var url = 'SHEET_URL';
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var webAppSheet = ss.getSheetByName("SHEE_ID");

  webAppSheet.appendRow([comapny, salutation, name, phone, email, appointment, room]);
  addMoreDetailsToRecord(); //just call your second function. you can add arguments to it if needed, too
}
```

This way, every time you run `AddRecord()`, `addMoreDetailsToRecord()` will also be executed at the end.

Comment: I considered the same solution and thought it was too easy to be true. But you just confirmed that simple solutions are sometimes the best. Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 1):

As [@Rodrigo Biffi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70080150/14271633) says, if you want the script to run right after `AddRecord`, you can always call the function at the end of it. To make sure that the changes have been executed you could use [`SpreadSheet.flush()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#flush)

###### `Code.gs`

```js
function AddRecord(comapny, salutation, name, phone, email, appointment, room) {
  var url = 'SHEET_URL';
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var webAppSheet = ss.getSheetByName("SHEE_ID");
  webAppSheet.appendRow([comapny, salutation, name, phone, email, appointment, room]);
  SpreadSheet.flush()
  addMoreDetailRow(webAppSheet)
}

function addMoreDetailsToRecord(webAppSheet) {
  var data = webAppSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var data_len = data.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < data_len; i++) {
    if (data[i][7] == "8:00 AM" && data[i][9] === "" && data[i][10] === "") {
      webAppSheet.getRange(i + 1, 9).setValue("NEW APPOINTMENT");
      webAppSheet.getRange(i + 1, 10).setValue("ROOM NUMBER ONE");
      webAppSheet.getRange(i + 1, 11).setValue("NAME OF ORGANIZER");
    }
    else if (data[i][7] == "10.00AM" && data[i][9] === "" && data[i][10] === "") {
      webAppSheet.getRange(i + 1, 9).setValue("NEW APPOINTMENT");
      webAppSheet.getRange(i + 1, 10).setValue("ROOM NUMBER TWO");
      webAppSheet.getRange(i + 1, 11).setValue("NAME OF ORGANIZER");
    }
  }
}
```

If the scripts are in two separate projects you could always [create](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/libraries#create_and_share_a_library) a **Library** and [add it](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/libraries#add_a_library_to_your_script_project) to your main project.

###### Documentation

- [Best Practices using Libraries](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/libraries#best_practices)

Comment: Your solution is good, too. Especially because I intend indeed to create a library later on. Thank you so much!!!